# How do I add these into dictionaries and make an active variable be the end after every 5 loops in python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, variables, median

Write a program that asks for a number and prints if the number is even or odd (like a roulette board):

- Keep track of numbers and responses
- After each result, display a summary of previous results
- After each result, the program should also report the median number
- The program should end using an active variable after it runs five times
- The program should end when quit has been entered
- The program should end if 0 is entered

This is the problem I was asked to do. I am able to do a simple one, but im not sure how to calculate the median or to make it so an active variable is the end variable after it runs five times.

```
odd = []
even= []

number=input("Enter a number, I will tell you if it's odd or even: ")
number = int(number)

while True:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("\nThe number" + str(number) + "is even.")
        even[number] = number
        print(even)
        print(median(even))
    elif number == 'quit':
        print('Done')
        break
    elif number == 0:
        print('Done')
        break
    else:
        print("\nThe number" + str(number) + "is odd.")
        odd[number] = number
```

Comment: I think you should put ``input()`` in ``while`` loop, because with this approach you just get the input once.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why or how will you use a dictionary in this situation, if you can let me know what will your 'key' and 'value' be?

Your 'odd' and 'even' type are lists, you should use odd.append or even.append to add results to each list.

Instead of having 2 'number' variables, you can do the following:

`number = int(input("Enter a number, I will tell you if it's odd or even."))`

Median is the middle point of a sequence arranged from smallest to largest. Example below will help you find median if length of your list is of even number, try your hand on an elif your list length is of odd number.

```
median = 0
my_list = [4, 2, 8, 6]
my_list.sort() #As mentioned, median requires a sorted list

if len(my_seq)%2==0:
    seq=(len(my_seq))/2
    seq_1=my_seq[int(seq-0.5)]
    seq_2=my_seq[int(seq+0.5)]
    median+=(seq_1+seq_2)/2
    print ('Length of this list is even, median of this list is {}'.format(median))
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.